# Why does a shared pointer put in a deque class get a read access violation during initialization？

Tags: c++, c++11

The below codes generates the `An exception was thrown: a read access violation. This was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7` error:

```
    std::deque<std::shared_ptr<int>> a(10);
    std::deque<std::shared_ptr<int>> b(&a[0], &a[2]);
```

but with an `int` as in the following code, it works correctly.

```
    std::deque<int> a(10);
    std::deque<int> b(&a[0], &a[2]);
```

The same occurs with the other initialization that I tried:

```
    std::deque<std::shared_ptr<int>> a(10, std::make_shared<int>(1));
    std::deque<std::shared_ptr<int>> b(&a[0], &a[2]);
```

Why is this?

Comment: What error?  Please formulate a complete question.

Comment: 例外がスローされました:読み取りアクセス違反。
this が 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7 でした。

Comment: Sorry, but you will need to add it in English. As per the site rules.

Comment: Reproduce I cannot: https://ideone.com/bTDADb More data is required.

Comment: An exception was thrown: a read access violation.
this was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7


This is a segmentation violation..

Answer (score 7):

What you are doing is actually *undefined behaviour*.

When you do this `b(&a[0], &a[2])` constructor ([constructs with contents of a range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/deque)), you are iterating over the `deque` not by an iterator but by a reference to each members memory location. You are not going to get a continuous iterator from pointers.

A `deque` is not necessarily continuous in memory (eg. if it is implemented as a linked list as in your case) . This means you are likely dereferencing memory that you do not own. It occurs in the second example as well, but you don't see it because the behaviour is undefined.

```
        Link               Link
    _____________    _______________    ______ ...
  |                |                  |
&a[0] [other mem] &a[1] [other mem] &a[2]   ...
       //^^^^^^^
       // When you iterate in b(&a[0], &a[2]), you iterate over this memory you dont own!
```

It could do anything, including throwing a `An exception was thrown: a read access violation.` or even work apparently correctly as it has done in your case. [Read about undefined behaviour here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

You can correctly initialize this with:

```
std::deque<std::shared_ptr<int>> b(a.begin(), a.begin() + 2);
```

[See a live example here.](https://ideone.com/wH9sJz)

Comment: I don't see that. `std::deque<std::shared_ptr<int>> a(10);` should make an a `deque` containing 10 `shared_ptr`s to NULL, so `a[2]` should be in bounds.

Comment: @user4581301 I fixed. I think that iterating between two memory sections in what is almost definitely a linked list is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ah. I see where you are coming from. Yes, Not going to get a continuous iterator from pointers. Update clears that up beautifully.

Comment: *Not going to get a continuous iterator from pointers* this line can be part of the answer.

Comment: On further mulling, this is bad juju, but might not be what the Asker's run into. A deque is a list of blocks of memory, and 10 is probably small enough that it will all fit inside the same block until you start adding and removing and elements and blocks.

Comment: @user4581301 Maybe it is more likely that when the deque creates itself it iterates over `a[0]->a[2]` by `sizeof(int)` and this is not what a single entry of deque contains?

Comment: I'm trying to get a canonical answer to what sort of iterator a `deque` provides. It definitely can't be contiguous and it's certainly bidirectional, but I'm not sure if it's random access, so I'm note sure if this: `std::deque<std::shared_ptr<int>> b(a.begin(), a.begin() +2);` eliminates this problem or merely causes another problem.

Comment: @user4581301 I think based on [std::deque::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/deque) allowing input iterator and std::deque::iterator being of type RandomAccessIterator, we can safely assume that will work.

Comment: Well compiler eats it (https://ideone.com/s0Xe3v) and rejects the same when I try it on the definitely not random access `std::list`.

Comment: @user4581301 Cool and thanks, i have added this to the answer.

Comment: Hey. There is it. Thank you. Didn't occur to me to text search the main page. I went digging under `deque::begin`

Comment: You might want to talk about what ctor the OP is calling (the two-iterator range one), as I was personally surprised the OP's code compiled until I spotted that!

Comment: @Yakk I added that detail and a link.

Comment: @Yakk it compiled because raw pointers can be treated as iterators